# (exam study help) Prove that there are infinitely many integers $m$ such that: $m^3 \equiv n^6 \pmod{19}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

I'm studying for a first year discrete math final exam. I was wondering if anyone could help me with this proof. I started by writing down what I know is true, but I can't seem to bring what I have so far to some meaningful conclusion.

Let $n$ be a fixed but arbitrary integer. Prove that there are infinitely many integers m such that:
$$m^3\equiv n^6 \pmod {19}$$

$$m^3\equiv n^6 \pmod {19} \Rightarrow 19|(n^6-m^3)$$
then:

$n=19k+r $  for $ k\in \mathbb{R}$

$m=19l+r $  for $ l\in \mathbb{R}$

$n^6=(19k+r)^6 $

$m^3=(19l+r)^3 $

now:

$$(n^6-m^3)=(19k+r)^6-(19l+r)^3$$

$$=19(k^6-l^3)+r$$

Comment: Nice title, hahaha! I was skimming and saw just “exam” and “help” and immediately had to open the post to see if anything shady was going on ;)

Comment: Well $0, 0$ is a solution.  And if if you have any solution $(m,n)$ then $(m + 19k, n + 19j)$ will be also solution and .... so was it *supposed* to be trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice m = $n^2$ is a solution
for the equivalence relation.
Assume there are only finite many solutions.
Let m be the largest.  m + 19 is a larger solution.
Thus there are infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 2):

$(m + 19k)^3 \equiv m^3 \mod 19$ so whatever is true about about $m$ and $m^3$ $\mod 19$ will be true about all infinite $m + 19k$ $\mod 19$

So if there exist *any* $m^3 \equiv n^6 \mod 19$ then there exist an infinite number of $(m + 19k)^3 \equiv n^6\mod 19$.

And for $m  = n^2$ we have $(n^2)^3 \equiv n^6 \mod 19$.